# Socket.io client connection to second server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I have a .NET app that is serving up an Angular 1.4 app. I'm running a second Angular app in the nav bar that connects to a second server running Node.js and Socket.io.

I can connect to the the **client to the server** when I'm running the server on my localhost via

`io.connect('http://localhost:8080')`

but not when I'm trying to connect to my Heroku instance via

`io.connect('http://my-weird-heroku-generated-url.com')`.

Is this because I'm not specifying the heroku port? Do I need to use the unaliased numeric IP address to my Heroku app (similar to the 127.0.0.1:8080 address/port to my localhost)?

Comment: Nope. But are you sure it's being served from :8080?

Comment: You do have to know what host AND port heroku is hosting your app on and you do need to connect to those.  The only time you don't have to include the port in the URL is if it is the appropriate default port such as port 80 (with an http:// url) or 443 (with an https:// url).

Comment: Do you know how I can get the url and port from Heroku?

Comment: That is, do you know how I can get the url and port from Heroku, and how would it look? E.g. would it look like `io.connect('http://my-weird-heroku-generated-url.com:80')`?